# Where should I place return false;?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a shopping cart script that works fine except after an item is add to the cart it jumps to the top of the page. Everywhere I place `return false:`it stops the information being added to the shoppingcart.php page.

PHP is this:

```
<?php
    include("includes/db.php");
    include("includes/functions.php");

    if ( isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command'] == 'add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0 ) {
        $pid=$_REQUEST['productid'];
        addtocart($pid,1);


    }
?>
```

Javascript is this:

```
<script language="javascript">
function addtocart(pid){
    document.form1.productid.value=pid;
    document.form1.command.value='add'; 
    document.form1.submit() ; 
    confirm('You have just added another item to the cart ') ;
}
```

This is the functions page.

```
<?php
function get_product_name($pid){
    $result=mysql_query("select name from employees where id=$pid");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result)or die(mysql_error());
    return $row['xname'];
}
function get_price($pid){
    $result=mysql_query("select price from xxxxxx where id=$pid");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['price'];
}
function remove_product($pid){
    $pid=intval($pid);
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        if($pid==$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid']){
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['cart']=array_values($_SESSION['cart']);
}
function get_order_total(){
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    $sum=0;
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
        $price=get_price($pid);
        $sum+=$price*$q;
    }
    return $sum;
}
function addtocart($pid,$q){
    if($pid<1 or $q<1) return;

    if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
        if(product_exists($pid)) return;
        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['productid']=$pid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['qty']=$q;
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['cart']=array();
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['productid']=$pid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['qty']=$q;
    }
}
function product_exists($pid){
    $pid=intval($pid);
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    $flag=0;
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        if($pid==$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid']){
            $flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $flag;
}
?>
```

Or should I be using a different request?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you needed to return false anywhere?

Comment: You submit the form. It does not “jump”, it’s being completely reloaded. You should use AJAX to yield the desired behaviour.

Comment: Sorry I've been googling for two days it was the closest I could find javascript is new to me. @mudasobwa Do I change this in the <script></script>?

Comment: Yes. Read the internet about ajax calls and perform ajax `POST` call instead of `form.submit()`.

Comment: @user2432677 just google `AJAX` and read the documentation. It's not that difficult and very useful.

Comment: Ok I've done some research and am thinking I have to use something like this.$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
}); So do I replace function addtocart(pid){
    document.form1.productid.value=pid;
    document.form1.command.value='add'; 
    document.form1.submit() ; 
    confirm('You have just added another item to the cart ') ;
}